# Not able to locate the published html page from Tridion

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I configured Tomcat as application server, Tridion deployer using eclipse and oData Web Service. I deployed two application in tomcat, TridionUpload and cd_webservice. Now I could publish successfully. But I am not able to locate the published html page. How can I view the published page? Please help.

Configuration in cd_storage_config.xml in TridionUpload application:

```xml
<Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultFile" defaultFilesystem="false">
    <Root Path="D:\Tridion\Temp" />
<!--<Root Path="c:\temp"/>-->
</Storage>
<Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultDataFile" defaultFilesystem="true" defaultStorage="true">
    <Root Path="D:\Tridion\Temp\Data" />
<!--<Root Path="c:\temp\data"/>-->
</Storage>

<Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="tomcatFS" defaultFilesystem="false">
    <Root Path="D:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\webapps" />
</Storage>
```

Configuration in cd_deployer_config.xml:

```xml
<Queue>
    <Location Path="D:\Tridion\ContentDelivery_Incoming\TridionUpload" WindowSize="20" Workers="10" Cleanup="true" Interval="2s"/>
<!--<Location Path="c:\tridion\work\http" WindowSize="10" Workers="10" Cleanup="true" Interval="30s"/> -->
</Queue>
<!-- Configure the HTTPSReceiver to store incoming package in specified location, and configure if deployer should run in process -->
<HTTPSReceiver MaxSize="10000000" Location="D:/Tridion/ContentDelivery_Incoming/TridionUpload" InProcessDeploy="true"/>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could you please check typeMapping node for example -

```
<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="false">
<Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile">
<Publication Id="XYZ" defaultStorageId="brokerFile" cached="false"></Publication>
</Item>
```

if you have not specified the `<Item typeMapping="Page`",by default page will go in to the database here it is "defaultdb".

Comment: If you have not able to find the solution with this answer please share more blocks of cd_deployer_config.xml so that I or someone else can assist you better.

Comment: <ItemTypes defaultStorageId="sqlserver" cached="false">  <Item typeMapping="Binary" storageId="tomcatFS"/>

Comment: Do you have <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile">
<Publication Id="XYZ" defaultStorageId="brokerFile" cached="false"></Publication>
</Item>
type block ? Please share complete <ItemTypes> node if possible

Comment: Please find cinfiguration in cd_storage_conf.xml           <ItemTypes defaultStorageId="sqlserver" cached="false">        <Item typeMapping="Binary" storageId="tomcatFS"/>              <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/> (commented) and publication node is commented.

Comment: Check your database or modify your cd_deployer_config.xml . Your page is going in the database

Comment: <ItemTypes defaultStorageId="sqlserver" cached="false">    
  
        <Item typeMapping="Binary" storageId="tomcatFS"/>
       
    </ItemTypes>

Comment: Add <Item typeMapping="Page" inside <ItemTypes node for your pages and also specify storageId ,if you do not want to save page in database .you can take help of code block in my answer

Comment: Ohh...I see.It is going to DB. But what I need to do to keep this page in webapp folder. So that I can access the page as part of my web application.

Comment: Step -1 set your path here in <root> 

<Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultFile">
<Root Path="d:\websites" />

(comment all other with Id="defaultFile")


Step-2-
 add <item> in  <ItemTypes> node as below  for you publication 

<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="false">
  <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile">
<Publication Id="XYZ" defaultStorageId="brokerFile" cached="false">
</Publication>
</Item>
</ItemTypes>

Do'nt forget to comment other similar node.

Hope you will smile after doing so :-)

Comment: superb!!! Now I can see my page but with associated files and folders. What can I mean for brokerFile? However my issue got resolved with a big smile. Thanks a lot.

Comment: brokerFile is StorageId for using filesystem as data storage.It is a custum name given by me in one of my project :-). if i see in your code in the question , you have it with name tomcatFS. anyway , there are few best practices for storing binaries,Query,SearchFilter and ComponentPresentation etc. After all your problem got resolved.see you in next discussion :-)